# Trace keys accessed on the NSDictionary used by Apple's Bluetooth API

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, nsdictionary, iobluetooth

Apple's Bluetooth API doesn't say what config dictionary should be provided for [IOBluetoothDevice openL2CAPChannelSync:withPSM:withConfiguration:delegate:].

The keys/values I'm suppose to provide are unknown to me. To overcome this, I wish to send an empty dictionary to the API call, but behind the scenes - track which keys are accessed.

How do I build a subclass of NSDictionary that will NSLog the accessed keys?

Comment: Well, as you said you can subclass NSDictionary and NSLog the accessed keys. I think your question needs a little more explanation, or I'm just tired...

Comment: I have this function: doSomething(dict). I don't know what keys/values doSomething expects to find in dict. so I want to find out which keys are accessed. (specifically, which configuration dictionary is needed for [IOBluetoothDevice openL2CAPChannelSync:withPSM:withConfiguration:delegate:]

Comment: I tried overriding @implementation NSDictionary (TracingMsg)
- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey {....  but it didn't work

Comment: If I understand you right, you "just need" to write NSLog("myLog, %@", key); into the right place, except you have no access to the source of doSomething and hence can never NSLog the key?

Comment: My problem is that Apple's Bluetooth API doesn't say what config dictionary should be provided for [IOBluetoothDevice openL2CAPChannelSync:withPSM:withConfiguration:delegate:]

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on top of doSomething's call and following the debugger into that call with 'step into'?

Comment: @eyalw let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3035/discussion-between-kheldar-and-eyalw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `IOBluetoothDevice` options, you should look in `IOBluetoothDevice.h`:

```
// These are for the configuration of L2CAP Channels:
#define kIOBluetoothL2CAPChannelMaxAllowedIncomingMTU       @"MaxAllowedIncomingMTU"
#define kIOBluetoothL2CAPChannelDesiredOutgoingMTU          @"DesiredOutgoingMTU"
```

Comment: Do you happen to know also how I set the channel QoS configuration? (like Guaranteed or Best Effort)

Comment: I don't know that this is settable. It's part of the `BluetoothL2CAPConfigurationOption` enum, but there in no public function that accepts this enum, and no public function that returns `BluetoothL2CAPConfigurationResult`. That suggests that there is no public way to set this kind of configuration. Much of IOKit is open source, but not the IOBluetooth section.